# How do I populate my form using Listview

Tags: vb.net

I've successfully taught myself how to pull some data from a MySQL database and bind it to a ListView control (ListViewCard).

Now I can't figure out how to use the SelectedIndexChanged event to inerate through the records and populate some other controls on my form (i.e, 7 textboxes, 2 comboboxes, and 2 datetimepickers).

Your help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's my code:

```
Private Sub loadCard()

    Try
        'FOR MySQL DATABASE USE
        'Dim dbQuery As String = ""
        'Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
        'Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbTable As New DataTable
        Dim i As Integer

        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password)
            dbConn.Open()
        End If

        dbQuery = "SELECT *" & _
                   "FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
                   "WHERE customer.accountNumber = '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "'"
        With dbCmd
            .CommandText = dbQuery
            .Connection = dbConn
        End With
        With dbAdapter
            .SelectCommand = dbCmd
            .Fill(dbTable)
        End With
        ListViewCard.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
            With ListViewCard
                .Items.Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccID"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccNumber"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccExpireMonth"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccExpireYear"))
                End With
            End With
        Next
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try
    dbConn.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the WPF tag because this sounds like WPF. If you are using WinForms, please adjust the tags accordingly.

Comment: No, no errors.  I just haven't figured out how to get the information currently being stored in my datatable out to my other controls.  Still researching though......

Comment: Thanks Cyborgx37, however, this is a WinForms application.

Comment: Use the selectedIndex on dbTable.Rows(i)(Column). Make  Dim dbTable As New DataTable available to the whole form.